# How are base 37 numbers represented as strings in python?

Tags: python

The following works fine:

```
num = int("python", base=36)
```

It works because because base 36 covers the characters  `0-9` and `a-z`

However, what string, `s`, would I need to represent decimal `97878380023034` such that

```
int(s, base=37) == 97878380023034
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int("0", base=37) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36, or 0
```

They aren't. The CPython `int()` function [explicitly checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/519cb8772a9745b1c7d8218cabcd2f96ceda4d62/Objects/longobject.c#L5098-L5102) that `((base != 0 && base < 2) || base > 36)` and errors if that returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int:

> If *x* is not a number or if *base* is given, then *x* must be a string, [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), or [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) instance representing an [integer literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers) in radix *base*. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by `+` or `-` (with no space in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of the digits 0 to n-1, with `a` to `z` (or `A` to `Z`) having values 10 to 35. The default *base* is 10. **The allowed values are 0 and 2–36.** Base-2, -8, and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with `0b`/`0B`, `0o`/`0O`, or `0x`/`0X`, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret exactly as a code literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16, and so that `int('010', 0)` is not legal, while `int('010')` is, as well as `int('010', 8)`.

<sup>(bold added)</sup> <sup>(Thanks to https://euangoddard.github.io/clipboard2markdown/ for making it easier to quote formatted text.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to define what to use for that novel 37th digit.  note that Python doesn't do this, I'd guess because it's a relatively uncommon task and/or there isn't a single obviously good choice.  assuming you were OK with making something up, we could do:

```
def int_digits(value, digits):
    base = len(digits)
    result = []
    while value:
        value, r = divmod(value, base)
        result.append(digits[r])
    return ''.join(reversed(result))

int_digits(97878380023034, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzX')
```

which gives me `rw1f4pXo6`.  note the presence of `X` which indicates that the 37th digit was needed here, but I presume you picked this example so it would